# How can I return 10 of the most recent results in sql?

Tags: sql, limit

This works fine and gives me the most recent results back:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC;
```

But when I put a limit on it to reduce the results to just 10 of the most recent, it doesn't give me the most recent results:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 30;
```

How else can I do this?

Comment: Did you actually mean `ASC` ? "Most recent" is best modeled with `DESC`, regardless of the limit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10;
```

the `DESC` clause asks for records with the most recent date first. Assuming your date field is a DATETIME-style field, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you order by id (or date) DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
SELECT Top(10) FROM table ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select top 30 * FROM table ORDER BY date ;
```